# Windows-Phone-7: Check if an instance of soundEffectInstance is playing

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio

I have a button that will control a sound effect. When the button is clicked, the sound should start to play. If you click it while the sound is still playing, it should stop the sound. If you click it after the sound stopped playing by itself, the sound should start playing again.

I have tried this, but I am using the SoundState method incorrectly, as it doesn't work:

```
public void playGenericSound(string fileName)
{
    if (playingSound.State != SoundState.Playing)
    {
        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(fileName))
        {
            var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            playingSound = effect.CreateInstance();
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            playingSound.Play();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        playingSound.Stop();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance!
Will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For XNA app:*

In the **update()** method check your sound effect's **playingSound.State** field and if the playback has stopped, play another one.

*For Silverlight:*

This part is a bit tricky since *SoundEffectInstance* was designed as a part of XNA. For example, you can make your own loop using a Timer and inside the event handler, add your state checking logic.

A second idea is to use a timer with it's interval set to the duration of your playing Sound and add a flag like **bool isPlaying**. When you play it for the first time set the **isPlaying** flag to *true* and start the timer. In the timer handler set the **isPlaying** flag to *false*. Each time your press the button check the **isPlaying** flag. In other words, make your own play-state logic.

You can combine these methods.

Comment: I have an application that's based on your second idea. Basically I built a queue that uses timers with the sound duration to control the queue flow. You need to make sure to build this in a robust way, handling errors and controlling the timers and events properly.

Comment: I had the same idea, but to be honest was hoping there would be a way to solve it without custom variables, particularly because I have multiple different sounds with different durations... which means a lot of custom timers. Will give it a try though. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post what I have done in a program I am working on now for someone.

```
// Play Audio File and allow stop
        if (new Rectangle(rV.X, rV.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height).Contains(mosX, mosY) && mouseClick)
        {
            if (driversmeeting.State != SoundState.Playing && !globalAudioPlaying)
            {
                globalAudioPlaying = true;
                driversmeeting.Play();
            }
            else if (driversmeeting.State == SoundState.Playing)
            {
                driversmeeting.Stop();
                globalAudioPlaying = false;
            }
        }
```